# Whats the best approach for Unit Testing with braintree

Tags: .net, braintree

I'm currently using the .NET SDK to process payments on my asp.net core project. I would like to automate tests using Unit Tests but it is proving difficult.

All the classes being used by the library - specifically "Subscription" and much more- have internal contructors or expect other internal instances. Options such as creating an instance from json to pass the it through a function is out.

It also not possible to construct an instance your self since the classes properties are all getters an with only the "*request" classes having setters but these arent't of much help since the application won't have to process them.

The Webhook test class is completely useless since the instance it gives is empty with only the id and status set. My application requires more data from a subscription such as the Transaction instance, Addons, Billing dates and more; all of which aren't populated.

I have several classes that require testing and having to do them manually is simply impracticle and wastes a lot of time. Is there another approach i am missing?

Why is the library designed like this, it doesn't seem very practicle in my opinion keeping the library so closed.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: @displayname Although I should have posted this when I found a solution it took me a few weeks, by which i'd forgotten about the question. Hope it's useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for that upgrade. Yes, it's always good to see how others solved that issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking, there is no possible way to unit test directly on the classes themselves without editing the library. On the bright side not all hope is lost, with the use of MOQ (https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) which allows you to mock classes -and more-. I used this to mock the classes that I was interested in testing, as an example, to create a transaction that I have full control over I would:

**Mock the transaction object.**

```
    public Mock<Result<Transaction>> SuccessTransaction_Mock { get; set; }

    public Result<Transaction> SuccessTransaction => SuccessTransaction_Mock.Object;
```

**Setup the methods your unit test is interested in checking.**

```
    // Success Transaction
    SuccessTransaction_Mock = new Mock<Result<Transaction>>();
    SuccessTransaction_Mock.Setup(s => s.IsSuccess())
            .Returns(true);
    SuccessTransaction_Mock.SetupGet(s => s.Target)
            .Returns(BtTransaction);
    SuccessTransaction_Mock.SetupGet(s => s.Message)
            .Returns("");
```

**Assert**

```
    Assert.True(SuccessTransaction.IsSuccess()) // Will return the value that was setup in the moq object
```

You are able to mock practically any of the classes in the Braintree Client library given the methods are virtual (most of the classes have interfaces which you can use).